# Unable to load a text through a local host

Tags: jquery, localhost, same-origin-policy, simplehttpserver

Question: **Why do I get an error that suggests this is "different-origin" material, and how do I fix it?**
I'm trying to recreate [this simple example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp) (click on "Try it yourself") on my machine using python's SimpleHTTPServer.  I've created a demo_test.txt (with same contents as example).  demo_test.txt and jquery-2.1.4.min.js are both in the root directory from where the server was started.  The code runs fine until it tries to access demo_test.txt, at which point is gives the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///Users/username/project/demo_test.txt. Cross origin requests
>   are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

If instead I try to load them as urls (commented out lines) I get a different error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I understand a bit about the same-origin policy, but I must be somehow violating it.  Can someone help me out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
        // $("#div1").load("http://127.0.0.1:8000/demo_test.txt");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can't run ajax from `file://` protocol. You aren't running on localhost at all. Need server running on your machine....lots of ways to do that

Comment: @ charlietfl: I run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in terminal, with output `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000...`  This is running a localhost, no?  And I understand your comment about file://, that's why I also tried as url.  Do you have a specific suggestion?

Comment: not really... are you loading html file through that ip and port? Doesn't matter that back end is ready to receive if the domain and protocol of the calling page aren' t the same as server

Comment: @charlietfl: I tried this line of code if that's what you're asking: `<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: no...browser address should be that same IP address and port or you aren't `serving` the file

Comment: @charlietfl: if I type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/demo_test.txt` into chrome address bar, it displays the contents of that file.  Isn't that an indication the local server is working?

Comment: not an html file? If backend running on that same ip and port should not see the `file://` error message on the ajax

Comment: @charlietfl: As I said, if I try to load with http:/127... I don't get a `file://` error, I get a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error.  The idea was to copy the example as closely as possible with minimal complications, so I kept it a .txt file (though did at one point try with .html extension instead)

Comment: right and the path you showed above was to `file:///Users/username/project/demo_test.txt` so it seems something is wrong in server config ... ***or***  you are not loading the html url from server and are just hitting file/open. You must have that html file running on same server

Comment: @charlietfl: `If instead I try to load them as urls (commented out lines) I get a different error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: I don't know what is happening ...just that when the html page loads...it needs to be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/htmlFileName.html` and then request should be received on same domain